# In Python, is there any functionality that checks if sub class has the method defined not super class

Tags: python, django, oop

Let's say:

```
class Human:
    def get():
      print("OK")

class Person(Human):
  def printw(a, b):
    print("ayush")

x = hasattr(Person, 'get')

print(x)
```

Output: True

But, I want that if subclass(Person) has a method "get", then only I should get True else not.

NOTE: I want to check in run time and all the inherited classes may not be available/known to me.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? The subclass *does* have the method – that's (part of) the point of inheritance. "I want to check in run time and superclasses may not be available" How is the class going to inherit if the superclass is not there?

Comment: Updated the qs, I just want to know in run time, and there can be situations, where I don't know how many classed I have inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this like following:

```
x = Person.__dict__.get('get') != None
```

This explicitly checks if the method is defined/overwritten in the class you are looking at.

Answer (score -1):

```
if hasattr(Person, 'get') and not hasattr(Human, 'get'):
```

Comment: That can be, but if there is multilevel inheritance, then this solution will not work. I guess.